# phpexcel in Codeigniter export data in database and sidebar template

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I export database to excel with library phpexcel successfully.
But when I open the file in excel, it is said unreadable content. But I can open and see my data.

Then I open the file using notepad, I see that code html of my sidebar is exported to in excel.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put

```
exit;
```

after

```
$objWriter->save('hp://output');
```

Example:

```
$objWriter->save('hp://output');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my project where I used **Phpexcel**.

My view page code (ourproduct.php):

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>ourproduct/download" class="btn btn-success" >Download .xls file</a>
```

My controller page (ourproduct.php):

```
public function download()  {
    $subscribers = $this->base_model->get_products();
    require_once APPPATH . '/third_party/Phpexcel/Bootstrap.php';
    $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
    $spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Webeasystep.com ')
            ->setLastModifiedBy('Ahmed Fakhr')
            ->setTitle('Phpecxel codeigniter tutorial')
            ->setSubject('integrate codeigniter with PhpExcel')
            ->setDescription('this is the file test');
    $styleArray = array(
            'font' => array(
                    'bold' => true,
            ),
            'alignment' => array(
                    'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                    'top' => array(
                            'style' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
                    ),
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                    'type' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                    'rotation' => 90,
                    'startcolor' => array(
                            'argb' => 'FFA0A0A0',
                    ),
                    'endcolor' => array(
                            'argb' => 'FFFFFFFF',
                    ),
            ),
    );
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:P1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    foreach(range('A','Q') as $columnID) {
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
                ->setAutoSize(true);
    }
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue("A1",'id')
            ->setCellValue("B1",'pro_code')
            ->setCellValue("C1",'hsn_code')
            ->setCellValue("D1",'pro_name')
            ->setCellValue("E1",'pro_brand')
            ->setCellValue("F1",'pro_price')
            ->setCellValue("G1",'pro_tax')
            ->setCellValue("H1",'pro_category')
            ->setCellValue("I1",'pro_scategory')
            ->setCellValue("J1",'pro_sscategory')
            ->setCellValue("K1",'pro_description')
            ->setCellValue("L1",'pro_filename')
            ->setCellValue("M1",'pro_date')
            ->setCellValue("N1",'pro_qauntity')
            ->setCellValue("O1",'pro_service')
            ->setCellValue("P1",'pro_certificate');
    $x= 2;
    foreach($subscribers as $sub){
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue("A$x",$sub['id'])
                ->setCellValue("B$x",$sub['pro_code'])
                ->setCellValue("C$x",$sub['hsn_code'])
                ->setCellValue("D$x",$sub['pro_name'])
                ->setCellValue("E$x",$sub['pro_brand'])
                ->setCellValue("F$x",$sub['pro_price'])
                ->setCellValue("G$x",$sub['pro_tax'])
                ->setCellValue("H$x",$sub['pro_category'])
                ->setCellValue("I$x",$sub['pro_scategory'])
                ->setCellValue("J$x",$sub['pro_sscategory'])
                ->setCellValue("K$x",$sub['pro_description'])
                ->setCellValue("L$x",$sub['pro_filename'])
                ->setCellValue("M$x",$sub['pro_date'])
                ->setCellValue("N$x",$sub['pro_qauntity'])
                ->setCellValue("O$x",$sub['pro_service'])
                ->setCellValue("P$x",$sub['pro_certificate']);
        $x++;
    }
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Users Information');
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="excel_sheet.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); 
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); 
    header('Pragma: public'); 
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

My model page (base_model):

```
public function get_products() {
    $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Change the field names with your requirements.